# Im stuck on how to set an array to my wanted output

Tags: java

Below is a screenshot and the wanted output. Everything I try yields nothing like the shape that I am trying to get.

Ive tried for loops, while loops, if statements, everything. I am a beginner java coder so any help would be appreciated. I would like the to be able to call the method that create the array using this code

```
public static char[][] getDiamonds(int rows) {
    char[][] diamond = new char[rows + 2][rows*2 + 1];

    for (int i = rows + 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        for (int j = rows * 2 - 1; j >= 0; --j) {
            diamond[i][j] = '/';
        }
        for (int j = rows * 2; j >= 0; --j) {
            if (j % 2 == 0) {
                diamond[i][j] = '\\';
            }
        }

    }
    return diamond;
}
```

Print method: (getDiamonds() is immediately passed into toString())

```
public static String toString(char[][] array) {
    String string = "";
    if (array == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Null array");
    }

    if (array.length == 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Empty array");
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length - 1; ++j) {
            string += array[i][j];
        }
        string += "\n";
    }

    return string;
    }
}
```

[Wanted output:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fmoX3.png)

A Diamond pattern with 1 row contains 2 lines. The first line contains a forward slash followed by a backslash. The second line contains a backslash followed by a forward slash. For example,

```
/\
\/
```

A Diamond pattern with 2 rows is made up of 3 lines and is formatted as shown below. The first line contains a space followed by a forward slash, a backslash, and a space. The second line contains 2 pairs of forward slash/backslash characters and the third line contains 2 pairs of backslash/forward slash characters.

```
 /\
/\/\
\/\/
```

A Diamond pattern with 3 rows is made up of 4 lines and is formatted as shown below. The first line contains 2 spaces followed by a forward slash, a backslash, and 2 spaces. The second line contains 1 space followed by a forward slash, backslash, forward slash, backslash, and 1 space. The third line contains 3 pairs of forward slash/backslash characters and the fourth line contains 3 pairs of backslash/forward slash characters.

```
  /\
 /\/\
/\/\/\
\/\/\/
```

Edited for everyone asking for basic code and changes from picture to text
Edited for print method

Comment: These are programming exercises that you need to figure out to understand how to code. At the very least show an attempt, because just asking for the answer verbatim won't help you. Take it step by step. If the line count is 4 then you need 2 spaces at the first line, and then 1, and then 0. I presume you see a pattern there, right? And then the first character is always a / except for that last line, which seems to be a special case.

Comment: At least show us code that creates a 2D array of some size, and then attempts to put something in it...

Comment: Hint: Get some GRAPH PAPER and draw the shapes that should be generated for 2 through 5 rows. Then look at the DIMENSIONS of the resulting patterns. How many rows does it need? How many columns does it need? You should be able to come up with a PATTERN and a FORMULA to translate the requested number of rows into the correct width and height.

Comment: A little hint, as it is very counter-intuitive, but you're best off using `new char[dimensionY][];`, so first the `y`- (lines, depth) and then the `x`- axis (columns). Then you can do `char[] line = diamonds[y]`

Comment: Or probably easier `char[][] diamonds = new char[lines][]` so you can do `char[] line = new char[columns]`, setting chars like `line[x] = '/'` and then finally `diamonds[y] = line`.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I'm not sure what you mean, I still have to set the size of my array to get all of the necessary characters. I am also very new to arrays so it could be my lack of knowledge.

Comment: I've added an answer where this is probably made clear, you can create the actual characters for each line.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, as multi-dimensional array handling is hard I'll give a hint, in the sense that the drawing still needs to be implemented using the methods:

```
public static char[][] getDiamonds(int rows) {
    // guard clause
    if (rows < 1) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("To create a diamond we need at least one (top) row");
    }
    
    int lines = rows + 1;

    // this creates an array that can hold lines
    // where each element is a char[] initially set to null
    char[][] diamonds = new char[lines][];
    
    for (int y = 0; y < rows; y++) {
        diamonds[y] = createTopLine(rows, y);
    }
    
    // rows is the last line index, as there is one more line
    diamonds[rows] = createBottomLine(rows); 
    
    return diamonds;
}

private static char[] createTopLine(int rows, int y) {
    // calculate amount of columns

    char[] line = new char[columns];

    // fill line

    return line;
}

private static char[] createBottomLine(int rows) {
    char[] line = ...

    ...

    return line;
}
```

Also, I'd strongly argue that you will also need to create a `print` method so you can see what you are doing:

```
private static void printDiamonds(char[][] diamonds) {
    // System.print(char) & System.println() are your friends
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following logic:

```
String one = "/\\";
String two = "\\/";

void getDiamonds(int rows) {
    List<String> rowStrings = new ArrayList<>();

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 1; i <= rows; i++) {
        addRow(i, builder, rows);
        rowStrings.add(builder.toString());
        builder = new StringBuilder();
    }

    builder.append(String.valueOf(two).repeat(rows));
    rowStrings.add(builder.toString());

    char[][] result = new char[rows + 1][rows *2];
    for (int i = 0; i < rowStrings.size(); i++) {
        result[i] = rowStrings.get(i).toCharArray();
    }

    return result;
}

void addRow(int rowNum, StringBuilder builder, int rows) {
    for (int i = 0; i < rowNum ; i++) {
        if (i == 0) {
            builder.append(" ".repeat(Math.max(0, rows - rowNum)));
        }
        builder.append(one);
    }
}
```

Have tested this for all rows values and seems to work

Comment: I didn't downvote you. A person who is just learning 2D arrays probably shouldn't be using Lists and StringBuilders. Stick to the basics...

Comment: @Idle_Mind It depends what you define as basics, because in my experience using a multi dimensional array is not very common. In 3 different work places I have been in it has never been used. Therefore I would consider using Strings as an easier solution.  But i take your point nonetheless

Answer (score 0):

Here are the first three diamond patterns, from heights 1 to 3:

```
/\
\/


 /\
/\/\
\/\/


  /\
 /\/\
/\/\/\
\/\/\/
```

Looking at the diamond patterns above for a given `height`, the number of rows in the 2D array would be `height + 1`. So a height of 5 would require 6 rows of output, while a height of 10 would require 11 rows. The diamond pattern itself can be thought of a combination of two parts. There are "upward facing points" that look like this `/\` in the top portion, and "downward facing points" that look like `\/` in the final bottom row.

Focusing on the upward facing points, the first row has one point, the second row has two points, while the third row would have 3 points, etc. The last row of upward facing portion will have `height` number of points. So a diamond with a height of 7 will have seven upward facing points in the second to last row of the overall pattern. Since the point is made from two characters, `/` and `\`, the width of that widest row will be `height * 2`. The bottom row, composed of downward points, `\/`, has the same number of points as the previous row.

Thus the dimensions of the required 2D array, given a specified `height`, would be:

```
Number of Rows = height + 1
Number of Columns = height * 2
```

For the diamond to be centered, though, the upwards facing points need to be offset with spaces so the overall diamond converges at a single point in the middle of the first row. The number of spaces required for each row is simply the height minus the current row. If this number is less than or equal to zero, then no spaces are needed. For example, with a diamond height of 5, the first row would need 5 minus 1, or 4 spaces. In the second row there would need to be 3 spaces since `5 - 2 = 3`. The third row would need 2 spaces since `5 - 3 = 2`, etc. The formula for the number of spaces required would then be:

```
Number of Spaces = height - row - 1;
```

We have to subtract one in the formula since arrays are zero based in Java.

The `toString()` function converts the 2D array to a single string using enhanced for loops. A 2D array can be thought of as an "array of arrays", as each row in the 2D array is really a single dimensional (1D) array. Here is a visual representation of a 2D array as an "array of arrays":

```
[
    [' ',' ','/','\',' ',' '],
    [' ','/','\','/','\',' '],
    ['/','\','/','\','/','\'],
    ['\','/','\','/','\','/']
]
```

You then have to decide how you're going to generate the rows, either from top to bottom, or from bottom to top. In the following code, I decided to go with top to bottom generation. Note that I use the `i` variable to track what column will get the next character in the current row:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int height;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    do {
      System.out.print("Positive Height of Diamond (-1 to Quit)? ");
      height = sc.nextInt();
      if (height>=1) {
        char[][] diamondArray = getDiamonds(height);
        String diamonds = diamondsToString(diamondArray);
        System.out.println(diamonds);
      }
      else if (height == -1) {
        System.out.println("Goodbye!");
      }
      else {
        System.out.println("Invalid diamond height!");
      }
    } while (height != -1);    
  }

  public static char[][] getDiamonds(int height) {   
    char SP = ' '; // space
    char FS = '/'; // forward slash
    char BS = '\\'; // backslash
    char[][] diamond = new char[height + 1][height * 2];

    int i; // tracks column next char goes into
    for(int row=0; row<diamond.length; row++) {    
      // spaces before
      int numSpaces = height - row - 1;
      for(i=0; i<numSpaces; i++) {
        diamond[row][i] = SP;
      }

      // points 
      int numPoints = row + 1;
      if (numPoints > height) {
        // adjust for the bottom row
        numPoints = height;
      }
      for(int p=0; p<numPoints; p++) {
        if (row < height) {
          // non-bottom row
          // upward facing points
          diamond[row][i++] = FS;
          diamond[row][i++] = BS;
        }
        else {
          // bottom row
          // downward facing points
          diamond[row][i++] = BS;
          diamond[row][i++] = FS;
        }
      }      
    }
       
    return diamond;
  }

  public static String diamondsToString(char[][] array) {
    String string = "";  
    for(char[] row : array) {
      for(char c : row) {
        string += c;
      }
      string += "\n";
    }
    return string;
  }
  
}
```

Here is a sample run showing various outputs:

```
Positive Height of Diamond (-1 to Quit)? -5
Invalid diamond height!
Positive Height of Diamond (-1 to Quit)? 1
/\
\/

Positive Height of Diamond (-1 to Quit)? 2
 /\
/\/\
\/\/

Positive Height of Diamond (-1 to Quit)? 3
  /\
 /\/\
/\/\/\
\/\/\/

Positive Height of Diamond (-1 to Quit)? 7
      /\
     /\/\
    /\/\/\
   /\/\/\/\
  /\/\/\/\/\
 /\/\/\/\/\/\
/\/\/\/\/\/\/\
\/\/\/\/\/\/\/

Positive Height of Diamond (-1 to Quit)? -1
Goodbye!
```